# Why smashing a sum change an horizontal spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, horizontal

I need to smash a sum because its indices take too much vertical space.  But then, it also change the horizontal spacing before it, as shown with the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blablabla blabla bla bla:
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N x = \frac{1}{2} \smash{\sum_{n=1}^N x}.
\end{equation}
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview:*
[image]

How can I smash the sum without changing the horizontal spacings around it?

(* The small red cow in the picture is a signature to this very nice piece of primitive art.  The picture is copyrighted and could be sold to MOMA!)

Comment: Try `\mathop{\smash{...}}`

Comment: not really smash, just `{\sum}` will get different spacing to `\sum`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, using braces gives the same horizontal problem.

Comment: That is what @DavidCarlisle just said.  The issue is not `\smash`...the issue is the braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases where a very high or deep object is better smashed; for instance, in an alignment where a formula ends with a summation and the next is much shorter, we can save vertical space by using `\smash[b]{...}` around the summation. Also your case can take advantage of smashing because of the short lines of text around the display.

However, one has to be aware that `\smash` (with or without the optional argument, for which one needs `amsmath`) always makes an ordinary atom. The nature of the object can be reinstated with the appropriate command, in this case `\mathop`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{1}{2} \mathop{\smash{\sum_{n=1}^N}} x.
\end{equation}
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N x.
\end{equation}
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.

\end{document}
```

Note that the `x` should go *outside* `\smash`.

[image]

In this particular case you might decide to smash also the fraction and the input can be simplified:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.
\begin{equation}
    x = \smash{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N x}.
\end{equation}
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N x.
\end{equation}
Blablabla bla bla blabla blaaaa.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be careful and do this refinements only when the document is in **final-no-more-changes-to-the-text-I-mean-really-really-final** state.

Comment: What's the [b] option to \smash?  Bottom smash only?  And I guess that [t] would be top smash only?

Comment: @Cham well guessed, that's indeed the meaning of the optional argument.

Comment: @Cham Yes: the people at AMS noticed that it would be handy in some situations to only smash the top or the bottom, so these options where added: `\smash[t]` smashes the top (above the baseline) and `\smash[b]` smashes the bottom (below the baseline). By the way, how's the picture of yours that of a cow? Everybody can see it's a lynx! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You asked,

> How can I smash the `\sum` without changing the horizontal spacing around it?

To `\smash` the expression without affecting the spacing between `\frac{1}{N}` and `\sum`, insert an empty math atom -- `{}` --  as the first element of the argument of `\smash`. For instance,

```
    \bar{x} = \frac{1}{N}\smash{{}\sum_{n=1}^N x_i}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,microtype,mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\[
    \bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_i  %% without \smash
\]
\hrule

\medskip
\hrule
\[
    \bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \smash{{}\sum_{n=1}^N x_i}
\]
\hrule

\medskip
\hrule
\[
    \bar{x} = \smash{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_i} %% too extreme, right?
\]
\hrule
\end{document}
```